# How to get this expression value model => model.Name?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I am trying to get below expression value by compiling and invoking but i get some errors and no success till now.

```
public static void TextEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var value = expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);//problem that is value is null

}
```

Comment: what code are you trying to execute? what are the errors?

Comment: "but i get some errors" - please be specific. Also - where is your model instance (to read at execution) coming from?

Comment: @Marc Gravell - updated my question

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham - I am asking get value not name

Comment: @FreshBlood you don't use value, so it isn't clear what the intent is... Also - it could be *correct* that it returns null.

Comment: @Freshblood: Deleted my comment, tho can't un-flag for dupe.  However, your question title disagrees with what you just said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(applies to the ***original*** question)

Given the signature, you should just need:

```
return Convert.ToString(
    expression.Compile().Invoke(modelInstance)
);
```

You can also do this by inspection of the expression if absolutely needed.

Comment: But what is purpose of converting null to String ? Invoke method returns null despite Model is not null.

Comment: @FreshBlood your original method signature returned `string`. If you didn't want a string, don't put that in the question :)  re the null - if .Name is null (I.e. the lambda naturally returns null), then you should expect a null. What else would you expect?

Comment: Your are right . Model property was null. Thats why result was null. Thanks

Comment: @FreshBlood to clarify, you mean that the `obj.Name` was null? If so, yes that is what I was saying

Comment: Yes, that is what i wanted to say

Answer (score 0):

Use [ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428393.aspx) and then its property `Model`

Comment: Good if i want to get Full metadata but not efective if i just need just value. Thanks